# JavaScript function runs before php script called by Ajax is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a function that I use to submit to Ajax, I call it submitAjax:

```
function submitAjax(Data){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.location,
        data: Data,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            var res = response;
        } 
    });
}
```

then I have functions that call to refresh a div, one of them being refreshPostResults:

```
function refreshPostResults(){
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open("GET", "post.php", false);
   xhttp.send(null);
   document.getElementById("refreshPostResults").innerHTML += xhttp.responseText;
};
```

Now I'll have a button for instance with the following onclick event:

```
<button type="button" onclick="submitAjax({'addViewCount': 29});refreshPostResults()">
```

Both the functions will work as if they are being called normally, there is nothing wrong with the functions, however, the refreshPostResults will run before the script on post.php finishes running and changing Session variables/database. Which therfore makes it seem like nothing happened on the front end when the button is pressed, but if you view the session variables or see the database you see that in the backend everything worked.

So I wanted to ask if anyone has a solution to this, preferably a solution that does not require me to change the submitAjax as it is used throughout the whole entire website, and almost every page has more than 30 submitAjax calls. Also, I did think about using a Settimeout() function from php, it's just that wouldn't using that function still allow for the same thing happening if the client's internet connection is poor, so it would take time to perform the submitAjax call

Comment: "before the script on post.php finishes running" - what does that mean? Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP?

Comment: Your `$.ajax` is simply _asynchronous_, so of course further code execution will not "wait" for it. _"Also, I did think about using a Settimeout() function from php"_ - stop right there, that is _never_ the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript and AJAX calls are asynchronous. This means they don't block the rest of your code from executing while they're waiting for a response from the server. In your case, refreshPostResults() is being called immediately after submitAjax(), without waiting for the AJAX request to complete.

You can fix this by putting your ajax function in a promise.

```
function submitAjax(Data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: window.location,
            data: Data,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                resolve(result)
            },

            error: function (error) {
                reject(error)
            },
        });
    });
}
```

Then use a different function to call your ajax script:

```
function submitData(){
    submitAjax({'addViewCount': 29})
    .then(() => {
        refreshPostResults();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}


<button type="button" onclick="submitData()">
```